# Missing CR LF (newlines) in scanned 2D barcode content in a web form field (or Notepad++)

Tags: notepad++, oracle-apex, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to scan a 2D barcode into a web page form field, on a Windows PC. I'm using a scanner device. Barcode contains around 10 values delimited with [CR][LF] and I believe the content is in order because:

- when I scan it into an ordinary Notepad, I get 10 lines with CR LF at the ends of all lines (HexEditor shows 0d 0a values)
- when I scan it with my mobile phone it also shows the content in newlines as it should

But, when I scan the content into  Notepad++ or my web page form field - the entire content is just one line. There is only one CRLF at the end of it, and it's because the scanner puts the end of line at the end of it's scanned content by default.

To be more exact, when I scan the content into the web page, the page registers linefeeds [LF] and does so as Ctrl+J which is a shortcut for the Downloads tab. So, it prints the first value into the field and then jumps to the Download tab and starts pasting the rest of the content in a single line.
I solved this with a Java script that prevents the default behaviour for Ctrl+J key event. Now I just get all the content in a single line in my field.

Why is Notepad++ (or my web page form field) not registering the carriage returns and linefeeds correctly?
Or - why is it behaving differently for the plain Notepad?

Any hint or advice on what I should look into is appreciated.

Comment: Even if it is summarized into items or stages, it will not be possible for others to investigate and reproduce it if it is only written in text. Please provide the minimum HTML page, related program source, barcode image, etc. that will allow others to reproduce the problem. Please refer to these help articles. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I understand it's not well explained. I was hoping someone with a similar experience (scanning delimited text) could give general explanation or insight into why Nopepad would act differently than Notepad++ when accepting scanned data. 
That might point me in the direction of knowing why a form field might behave in the way I described.

Answer (score 0):

My goal was to scan a 2D barcode (utility bill, PDF417 type) with multiple values into an Oracle Apex web page with multiple fields.
The values in the barcode were delimited with CRLF's.

My problem was that once I scanned the barcode, only the first value was passed into a field I was positoned in, and then the browser jumped to the Downloads tab and dumped the rest of the values into a search bar (single line).
From my understanding - Chrome sees LF as a Ctrl+J event and that is a shortcut to the Downloads tab.

I'm not going to type in the barcode or the scanner type or anything else because that's not important. You've either ran into this problem and you know what I'm talking about or you haven't.

My solution was that since the browser did manage to catch LF's (even though in a bad way, like Ctrl+J) I wrote a javascript code that ignored the Ctrl+J event and also copied the content of my field into a second field that I used like a concatenation placeholder.
This I pasted into "Execute when page loads":

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
   // Check if CTRL and J are pressed
   if (event.ctrlKey && (event.key === 'j' || event.key === 'J'))  {
      // Prevent the default behavior (opening the downloads window)
      event.preventDefault();
      
      // Concat the partial scanned value into a concat field
      $s("P220_CONCAT", $v("P220_CONCAT") + $v("P220_FIRST_FIELD")+'|');
      $s("P220_FIRST_FIELD", "");
   }
});
```

Also, I made a "on change" dynamic action of the Concat filed to send the concatenated string into a DB procedure to parse it and Return the values into form fields to fill them up.
It's a bit more complicated but I won't go into those details. My goal is to leave my solution here, for other Apex developers that might run into the same problem.

Also, if there are better solutions - I'm all ears :)